# Can't install flash with winetricks

Tags: wine, flash, playonlinux, winetricks

I run `winetricks flash` and it outputs

```
Executing w_do_call flash
Executing load_flash
Downloading http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/12.0.0.38/install_flash_player_ax.exe to /home/mina/.cache/winetricks/flash
--2015-10-31 21:31:31--  http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/12.0.0.38/install_flash_player_ax.exe
Resolving fpdownload.macromedia.com (fpdownload.macromedia.com)... 23.39.241.142
Connecting to fpdownload.macromedia.com (fpdownload.macromedia.com)|23.39.241.142|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-10-31 21:31:32 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/pdc/12.0.0.38/install_flash_player_ax.exe failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the correct way to install flash in wine?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of Winetricks from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks